# read recursive array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion

I have this json from google api:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {

         "formatted_address" : "1 Broadway, New York, NY 10021, USA",
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

how to get the value of "formatted_address"?

with this code (using jquery) I only get "results is Array"

```
$.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data){

    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        alert(key + ' is ' + val);
    });

});
```

In php it is very easy but I need this to be client-side

Comment: `data.results[0].formatted_address`

Comment: When you solved your problem please delete your question (in case there are no answers yet) or answer your own question - but do not put "solved" in the title.

Comment: I think the keyword recursive in the title is misleading.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have low reputation so I had to wait 7hrs before self-answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(key, val) {
        alert(key + ' is ' + val);
    });
});
```

This should work.

Comment: You mean `data.results` rather than `data[results]`

Comment: what is the difference between both dara.results and data['results']